# Save a hex-string to PostgreSQL column character varying

Tags: postgresql, hex

I want to save hex-string ('A2-5A-47-00-10-00-00-00') into a PostgeSQL database.

My column is character varying(30).

How can I do this?

Comment: just insert it in single brackets?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that there are never more than 10 elements, you can simply cast your hex string to `text`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (hex_text) VALUES (<some hex data>::text);
```

Or use a `bytea` column instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

My column definition was wrong character varying 
instead of  character varying(30).